# Excel: Replacing html tags with line break

Tags: excel, vba

I have spreadsheets that contain html. It's ugly. I can strip out the html using VB:

```
Replace What:="<*>", Replacement:="",
```

This is tidier, but I lose line breaks that make the text more readable. What I'd like to do is insert a line break before e.g. `<li>`. `Chr(10)` is VB for insert line break, but this doesn't insert the line break:

```
Sub listItem()
Cells.Replace What:="<li>", Replacement:=Chr(10) & " - ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End Sub
```

It replaces `<li>` with the hyphen, but no line break. It doesn't throw an error. I'm assuming I'm using Chr(10) incorrectly but I could use some help.

Comment: hi paul. I just copied and pasted your code and worked fine for me. maybe you can set the worksheet, just in case.

Comment: another option is to use    `vbNewLine` instead of     `Chr(10)`. can you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, your code worked fine for me however you have other options to create a nextline:

```
(Chr10)
vbNewLine 
vbLf
vbCrLf
```

all these constants can be used as new line. I do not know what are the differences but all of them works fine for me :)

You can try these and see if they work.